# How to mock an axios api call to return different values based on input?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs, axios

Say one has a function that, among other tasks, makes a few api calls using axios. Is there a way, when testing this function, to mock all the axios api calls and specify return values from the calls depending on the input. For example, say the function you want to test is this:

```
function someFunction (a, b, c) {
    const apiReturnA = axiosApiCall(a)
    const returnB = b + 1
    const apiReturnC = axiosApiCall(c)
    return [apiReturnA, returnB, apiReturnC]
}
```

I'd like to test `someFunction` and specify that, every time `axiosApiCall` gets called, don't execute the function, simply return a value based on the input to this function. How can one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject `axiosApiCall` via a closure:

```js
function apiWrapper(axiosApiCall) {
    return function someFunction (a, b, c) {
        const apiReturnA = axiosApiCall(a)
        const returnB = b + 1
        const apiReturnC = axiosApiCall(c)
        return [apiReturnA, returnB, apiReturnC]
    }
}


const testApiCall = function(input) {
    return input * 2;
}
let someFunction = apiWrapper(testApiCall);
console.log(someFunction(1,2,3));
```

And then in your real code you just pass in the real `axiosApiCall`